# WPF - ItemTemplate not acting as expected

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate, itemtemplate, itemspanel

I have a `UserControl` which I'm using to display a list of `UIElement`s.  The control consists of a single `ItemsControl` with it's `ItemPanelTemplate` switched for a horizontal `StackPanel`, its `ItemsSource` bound to a `DependencyProperty` exposed by the `UserControl` and its `ItemTemplate` set in the `UserControl.Resources`.

Everything works fine except the `ItemTemplate` never get's applied and I can't see why.  The full source is below.

UserControl.xaml -

```
<UserControl x:Name="UC" x:FieldModifier="private" x:Class="ContentSliderControl.ContentSlider"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="pageTemplate">
        <Border CornerRadius="10" Padding="5" Height="200" Width="200" Background="#333">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="template">
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ItemsControl ItemsPanel="{StaticResource template}" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pageTemplate}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UC,Path=Pages}"/>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs -

```
[ContentProperty("Pages")]
public partial class ContentSlider : UserControl
{


    public List<UIElement> Pages
    {
        get { return (List<UIElement>)GetValue(PagesProperty); }
        //set { SetValue(PagesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Pages.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PagesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Pages", typeof(List<UIElement>), typeof(ContentSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



    public ContentSlider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

}

I consume the control in my main window like this -

```
    <slider:ContentSlider >
    <slider:ContentSlider.Pages>
        <Button>1</Button>
        <Button>2</Button>
        <Button>3</Button>
        <Button>4</Button>
    </slider:ContentSlider.Pages>
</slider:ContentSlider>
```

The buttons appear fine but not inside the 200px square border.

Any help would be greatlly appriciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because it's a list of UIElement, the item template is only applied if the items can't be displayed directly.

Comment: Also, if i swap the ItemsControl for a Listbox then they render as expected so I'm not sure you're right there

Comment: Seems I have to eat my words!  Thanks Nir.

Answer (score 6):

Nir is correct, `ItemsControl` will add item directly to its `Panel` if they are UIElements.  I couldn't find any mention of this behavior in MSDN, but Dr. WPF mentions it in [his article on item containers](http://drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/32/Default.aspx):

> If a UIElement is added to the Items collection of an explicit ItemsControl instance (as opposed to an instance of a derived class like ListBox), it will become a direct child of the items panel. If a non-UIElement is added, it will be wrapped within a ContentPresenter.

Your solution is probably to use a `ListBox` instead, and set `ItemContainerStyle` to a new `Style` for `ListBoxItem`, and in that style, use a `ControlTemplate` with your `Border` in it.

Comment: Well isn't that some crazy behavior.  Thanks for that Robert, I'll give Nir the correct answer then and vote you up.  Shame you can't have more than one correct answer eh?

Answer (score 4):

Nir is right, this custom ItemsControl implementation will solve the issue and let use your own ItemTemplate:

```
public class ItemsControlForUIElement : ItemsControl
{
   protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
   {
       return new ContentPresenter();
   }
   protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Robert Macnee nailed the reason on the head.  His solution involves using the control template which might be overkill for a given scenario.  Alternatively, use a `ListBox` - set the `ItemContainerStyle` to a new Style for `ListBoxItem`, and in that style, set the `ContentTemplate` to the `DataTemplate` that you wanted to use in the `ListBox` `ItemTemplate`.

Answer (score -1):

If you set the `DataType` property on the `DataTemplate` it would start working.